# css/javascript visibility visible/hidden is very slow on Blackberry 

Tags: javascript, css, visibility, hidden

```
document.getElementById("spinner2").style.visibility="visible"
```

Visibility visible/hidden is very slow on Blackberry (OS4.6).  The screen seems to be redrawing which makes it unusable in Ajax application.

The goal is to put visible feedback to user while ajax request completes.

Can anyone any suggest any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the layout you'll get redraw. If a single redraw is slow then you're layout is too heavy for a mobile application i guess.

Comment: layout is fairly heavy, but I am using ajax to compensate.

Comment: ajax is about network efficiency not rendering. You can't compensate a heavy layout with ajax.

Comment: ajax techniques permit developers to build heavy layout (by which I mean, many functions
on a page and several hundred lines of html/js) while at the same time having nible
performance by using ajax to replace only small amounts of html at a time on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is `document.getElementById("spinner2").style.display = "block"` any better? You would have to start with `display: none` on the spinner element, and you would need to put it in a fixed box (div) to keep it from re-flowing the layout.